# empty json when using body-parser bodyParser.json()

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, body-parser

I am trying to send a long json as a post request via script in an HTML page like: (the data comes from a textbox and it is a correct array of json)

```
<script>
        /* UPDATE ORGANIZATION LIST*/
        function updateOrgs () {
            var data = $('#showOrgs').val();

            $.ajax({
                url : "http://localhost:8000/api/updateOrgs",
                type: "POST", // data type (can be get, post, put, delete)
                data : {json:JSON.parse(data)}, // data in json format
                async : false, // enable or disable async (optional, but suggested as false if you need to populate data afterwards)
                success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown)
                }
            });
        }        
</script>
```

I have set up my express as:

```
const express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
// initialize express
const app = express();

// body-parser
// create application/json parser
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
 
// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})
```

I am using the body-parser in my node express app to read the json in the body such as:

```
app.post('/api/updateOrgs', jsonParser, (req, res)=> {
    try {
        console.log(req.body);
        // send response
        res.send('Successfully updated');
    } catch (e) {
        res.send(e);
    }
});
```

**The Problem** is that my express app prints an empty object `{}`. So is it because the json file that I am posting is very big? It has 64 object in an array.

Or the issue comes from the usage of the express app that uses the body-parser module as `app.post('/api/updateOrgs', jsonParser, (req, res)=> {`?

Comment: You're probably missing the Content-Type: application/json header

Comment: does it work for small json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json',
data : JSON.stringify({json:JSON.parse(data)}),
```

All code:

```
<script>
        /* UPDATE ORGANIZATION LIST*/
        function updateOrgs () {
            var data = $('#showOrgs').val();

            $.ajax({
                url : "http://localhost:8000/api/updateOrgs",
                type: "POST", // data type (can be get, post, put, delete)
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data : JSON.stringify({json:JSON.parse(data)}), // data in json format
                async : false, // enable or disable async (optional, but suggested as false if you need to populate data afterwards)
                success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert(response);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown)
                }
            });
        }        
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `bodyParser` object exposes various factories to create **middlewares**. All middlewares will populate the req.body property with the parsed body when the Content-Type request header matches the type option, or an empty object ({}) if there was no body to parse, the Content-Type was not matched, or an error occurred.

**bodyParser.json([options])**

Returns middleware that only parses json and only looks at requests where the Content-Type header matches the type option. This parser accepts any Unicode encoding of the body and supports automatic inflation of gzip and deflate encodings.

A new body object containing the parsed data is populated on the request object after the middleware (i.e. req.body).

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
// POST /login gets urlencoded bodies
app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.username)
})

// POST /api/users gets JSON bodies
app.post('/api/users', jsonParser, function (req, res) {
  // create user in req.body
})
```

**Change accepted type for parsers**

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse various different custom JSON types as JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }))

// parse some custom thing into a Buffer
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/vnd.custom-type' }))

// parse an HTML body into a string
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'text/html' }))
```